# I'm having trouble implementing the String's substring method recursively

Tags: java, string, recursion

```
public String substring(String s, int start, int stop){
    if(stop>s.length()||start>stop||start<0){
       throw new IllegalArgumentException("");
    }
    if(start==stop){
        return "";
    }else{
        return ""+s.charAt(start)+substring(s, start++, stop);
    }
}
```

I am getting stack overflow and I'm not sure how to fix it

Answer (score 1):

That's because `start++` firstly returns `start` value and **then** incrementing `start`'s value (that means that you are basically calling recursively `substring` function with always the same `start` parameter's value) - you need to change this to `++start`

```
return ""+s.charAt(start)+substring(s, ++start, stop); // or even better 'start + 1' because you don't need to increment this locally
```

Comment: Thank you that fixed it. So `start++` doesn't change the value of start passed in as a parameter but `start+1` does?

Comment: Writing `start++` as an argument to a method passes the original value of start to that method, and then increments the value of `start`  in the module that called that method.

Comment: Yup, additionaly `start + 1` will not modify the `start` variable locally but basically seems that you don't need this modification. Remember that all parameters in Java are being passed **by value**